How can I publish ios app worldwide outside Appstore
I developed an alcohol level calculator app for an association, but despite all modifications, Apple always refuse it. However similar app already exists.
So I thought publishing the app outside of the appstore. I found few solutions on internet, but they seems to only works with Enterprise accounts, of for testing, i.e with registered devices.
Is there a way to do it without all these restrictions?
Thanks for your suggestions

You cannot. You could develop a web site

This is called sideloading, this is possible for EU users only.

Apple is opening up web distribution for iOS apps targeting users in the European Union starting April 16, 2024


In order to do so developers will have to opt into Apple’s new EU business terms, which include a new “core technology fee” charged at €0.50 for each first annual install over 1 million in the past 12 months regardless of where apps are distributed. App makers wishing to avoid the fee currently have no choice but to remain on Apple’s old business terms, meaning they are unable to access any of the DMA entitlements.

